# Adding a Where Clause to a OleDbCommand

Tags: c#, combobox, where-clause, oledbcommand

I am trying to add a where clause to the following line of code.

the reason for this is because i get the datatable from a dropdown combobox. now i want to filter that table on user name, so that only the user can see their records.

i need help on how to write the where clause into this code.

if you need any more information i will gladding add it.

thank you for any help.

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(String.Concat("Select * From ", comboBox1.Text), con);
```

***After Comments***

i added the sql injection protection.

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(String.Concat("Select * From 
@Companydetails where Research_ID = @Researcher_ID"), con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Companydetails", comboBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Researcher_ID", usernumber_lab.Text);
```

but now it is giving me a error saying:

> Additional information: Syntax error in query.  Incomplete query clause.

is there something else i need to add to finnish this query off?

Comment: So what's stopping you?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), if you have time I suggest you read a bit about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
string sql = String.format("Select * From {0} where id = {1}", comboBox1.Text, id);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql,con);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it as follows;

```
string query = "Select * from MyTable Where username = @username";

using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con))
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
}
```

This way the object will dispose automatically and also you'll be safe from Sql Injection

Comment: The OP mentioned that the table name came from a dropdownlist as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make your sql statement longer:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(String.Concat("Select * From table Where something = something", comboBox1.Text), con);
```

You don't have to work with multiline or anything. This is only needed in some database managers, but not in a c# sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(String.Format("Select * From {0} WHERE username='{1}'", comboBox1.Text,username.Text), con);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format(
                                  "SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE Username = '{1}'",
                                  comboBox1.Text, userName), con);
```